# Does Instagram has Dynamic feed API

Tags: instagram-api

Does Instagram has Dynamic feed API which pulls latest feed automatically similar to twitter API's ? I am looking to build a custom widget to show latest feed of Instagram always shown on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following endpoint to get the most recent media published by the owner of the Instagram account:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

You need to pass in the parameters as well:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN    A valid access token.
COUNT   Count of media to return.
MIN_ID  Return media later than this min_id.
MAX_ID  Return media earlier than this max_id.
```

With this endpoint, the most recent media will be the first to get returned to you. Also, this endpoint requires the owner of the media to be the same as the `access_token` owner.

You can read more about other endpoints on in the [Instagram API Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).